# pandas merge multiple Dataframes and the do text analysis?

Tags: excel, python-2.7, pandas, text-analysis

## Problem statement:

I have this crummy file from a government department that lists the operation schedules of 500+ bus routes across multiple sheets in a single excel. There is really no structure here and the author seems to have a single objective - pack everything tight in a single file !

Now, what am I trying to do:

Do extensive text analysis to extract the starting time of each run on the route. Please note there are multiple routes on a single sheet and then there are around 12 sheets in all.

I am cutting my teeth with the pandas library and stuck at this point:

Have a dictionary where 
Key:   sheet name (random str to identify the route sequence)
Value: DataFrame created with all cell data on that sheet.

## What do I would like to know:

1. Create one gigantic DataFrame that has all the rows from across the 12 sheets. Start with my text analysis post this step.
2. Is that above the right way forward?

Thanks in advance.
AT

Answer (score 0):

Could try a multi-index dataframe:

```
df_3d=pd.concat(dfs, # List of dataframes
                keys=sheetnames,   # List of sheetnames
                axis=1)
```

Where dfs would be something like

```
dfs=[read_excel(io,sheetname=i) for i in sheetnames]
```